# How can I get a tshark ring buffer working

Tags: packet-capture, tshark, sniffer

I'm trying to use tshark (version 1.10.14) on a FreePBX system to capture sip traffic so I can figure out why we have audio dropouts. It runs fine if I just tell it to run for a while and stop. But I want it to run continuously so that when the problem happens I can stop it and know I have the needed packets.

I have tried a number of example command-line arrangements. This looks to me like it should work:

```
tshark -a filesize:10000 -b files:6 -i eth0 -w tcap2.pcap
```

But when I try it, or really anything with the filesize or files parameters, I get "The file to which the capture would be saved ("tcap2.pcap") could not be opened: No such file or directory."

I already learned that tshark won't work if the file doesn't already exist. So the file does exist and is in the current directory. Found a few old "solutions" to this problem but none of them work.

Any help would be appreciated. For now I will just have to run it manually and delete the files if they don't capture what I need.

Comment: First, that version of `tshark` is very old, having gone End-Of-Life nearly 6 years ago, so it's no longer supported.  You might want to upgrade, if possible.  That said, you seem to be mixing autostop and ring buffer settings; is that what you want, or maybe you want `-b filesize:10000` instead?  And `tshark` **will** work if the file doesn't already exist, so another reason to upgrade if that's the behavior you're seeing.  Also, make sure you have suitable permissions to be able to write and create files in the directory you're running `tshark` from.

Comment: I tried upgrading tshark by installing the latest available version of wireshark...it installed the same version. I guess I am going to have to compile it myself but this is a production PBX that will need a lot of dev stuff. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you want to capture continuously, then I recommend using [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html) instead since it's stateless, unlike `tshark`, thus it won't continue consuming more and more memory the longer you run it. Maybe you'll have better luck with using `dumpcap` directly, which is what `tshark` uses under the hood anyway. You could also try [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html), which offers similar functionality using `-G rotate_seconds`, `-C file_size` and `-W filecount` options. It depends on the version available on your system though.

Comment: Update: I am running FreePBX on this server. It uses a custom distro based on CentOS 7 called Sangoma Linux. Once I found where repos are located on this distro and placed wireshark.repo there I was able to uninstall the current wireshark version and install the newest one. Once I did that, tshark works exactly as advertised. Thanks!

Comment: I had tried dumpcap previously and it gave the same error as tshark. I believe tshark uses dumpcap and both are probably upgraded now that I resolved the initial problem. But I with try that and also tcpdump as well so I will have some options.